# How can I get notifications of new emails?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, email

I was wondering, is there any way to get an on-screen notification when a new email is received, like in Google talk.

Comment: Have you set up your mail account in Thunderbird? Thunderbird uses desktop notifications when you receive  a new email.

Comment: @UriHerrera but thunderbird also needs to be running.

Comment: but doesn't it run the background?

Comment: @UriHerrera no.

Answer (score 1):

That type of program is known as [biff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biff), so that might help in searching.
Here is a biff that works on Gnome for Gmail: [cGmail](http://cgmail.tuxfamily.org/)

Comment: cGmail doesn't work for me bro :(

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of applications that can do it. try it all and see what works for you the best.

my recommendation is:

- if you are using unity, [unity mail](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/08/unity-mail-gmail-count-desktop-launcher-ubuntu/)
- if you are using gnome shell, [mailnag](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/install-mailnag-gnome3-email-notifier.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are various applications in the software centre that can do this. Search for "gmail", and then check your list of options, and choose one.

I have tried gmail-watcher and others, and all pretty much do the same job, and do it well :).