# how do you setup email notifications with thunderbird, for when the main app isnt open?

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get notifications of new emails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83441/how-can-i-get-notifications-of-new-emails)

how do you setup email notifications with thunderbird, for when the main app isnt open?
im trying to setup a way to get notifications of emails without having to have thunderbird open. 
would be nice to click the notification then thunderbird opens to read it.
like a small background program running that checks for new emails every 5-10 minutes.

is there such a setting?

thanks for any help!
Alex

Comment: The sort of program you want is called a biff. There are many. http://askubuntu.com/questions/83441/how-can-i-get-notifications-of-new-emails

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. How should Thunderbird check for emails without being started?

you could install an extension which allows you to start Thunderbird minimized

[such as this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/minimize-on-start-and-close/)

all you have to do now is to start Thunderbird with your System, autostart can be found at the **gnome session properties**, just hit <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type in **gnome-session-properties**.

Click the **Add** button and just add Thunderbird to it.

Last but not least, how to check periodically? Simply go to the email account settings by

**rightclick the E-Mail Account -> Settings -> Server Settings** and check the option

**[ x ] Check for new messages every *_*__ minutes**

(p.s.: since i can't take screenshots right now i just highlighted it, i will add screenshots later)